# Converting list items as multiple dictionaries in a single list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am working on a project to create a Python dictionary.
I have got two lists:

```
table_name=['new1','new2']
field_names=[['apple','banana'],['orange','Mellon']]
```

I tried this code:

```
dct = {}
for x in range(0, len(table_name)):
   dct[table_name[x]] = field_names[x]
```

I got this dictionary:

```
{"new1" : ['apple','banana'], "new2" : ['orange','Mellon']}
```

I want to something like that:

```
{"new1" : [{'name':'apple'},{'name':'banana'}], "new2" : [{'name':'orange'},{'name':'Mellon'}]}
```

I hope someone can share the right approach to do this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `zip` here.

```
table_name=['new1','new2']
field_names=[['apple','banana'],['orange','Mellon']]
d1={}
for k,v in zip(table_name,field_names):
    d1[k]=[{'name':i} for i in v]
```

---

```
{'new1': [{'name': 'apple'}, {'name': 'banana'}],
 'new2': [{'name': 'orange'}, {'name': 'Mellon'}]}
```

---

*Dict-Comprehension* of the above would be:

```
{k:[{'name':i} for i in v] for k,v in zip(table_name,field_names)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
dct = {k : [{'name' : j} for j in field_names[i]] for i,k in enumerate(table_name)}
```

**Output** :

```
{'new1': [{'name': 'apple'}, {'name': 'banana'}], 'new2': [{'name': 'orange'}, {'name': 'Mellon'}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below:

```
json_data = {"new1": ['apple', 'banana'], "new2": ['orange', 'Mellon']}
output_dict = {}
for obj in json_data.keys():
    output_dict[obj] = list(map(lambda x:{'new': x}, json_data[obj]))
print(output_dict)
```